# Squid SSL transparent proxy - SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid, openssl, transparent-proxy

I am trying to setup a SSL proxy for one of my internal servers to visit `https://www.googleapis.com` using Squid, to make my Rails application on that server to reach `googleapis.com` via the proxy.

I am new to this, so my approach is to setup a SSL transparent proxy with Squid. I build `Squid 3.3` on Ubuntu 12.04, generated a pair of ssl key and crt, and configure squid like this:

```
http_port 443 transparent cert=/home/larry/ssl/server.csr key=/home/larry/ssl/server.key
```

And leaves almost all other configurations default. The authorization of the dir that holds key/crt is `drwxrwxr-x  2 proxy proxy    4096 Oct 17 15:45 ssl`

Back on my dev laptop, I put `<proxy-server-ip> www.googleapis.com` in my `/etc/hosts` to make the call goes to my proxy server.

But when I try it in my rails application, I got:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
```

And I also tried with openssl in cli:

```
openssl s_client -state -nbio -connect www.googleapis.com:443 2>&1 | grep "^SSL"
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Does this file really contain your cert?

```
  cert=/home/larry/ssl/server.csr
```

If you're following standard conventions, that's your CSR, certificate signing request, that you sent to your SSL vendor.  The SSL vendor, in return, gave you a certificate (often .crt) file that you need to use here.

Comment: No, that's not from a SSL vendor, it's a self signed csr.

Comment: But a csr is usually a certificate signing request, not the certificate itself.